# How to shred Column names as well as data from the XML

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, shred

I have a XML which has a header group with column names and a data group with the actual data belonging to those columns.

Sample XML:

```
<headerGroup> 
   <data> 
      <string>Column 1</string> 
   </data> 
   <data> 
      <string>Column 2</string> 
   </data> 
</headerGroup> 
<dataGroup> 
   <data> 
      <string> abcd </string> 
   </data> 
   <data> 
      <double> 1234</double> 
   </data> 
</dataGroup> 
<dataGroup> 
   <data> 
      <string> xyz</string> 
   </data> 
   <data> 
       <double> 78945</double> 
   </data> 
</dataGroup>
```

I need to shred this xml into a table with those column names and corresponding data. Expected output:

```
Column 1      Column 2
------------- ------------------- 
abcd           1234 
xyz           78945
```

The column names and data do not share the same tags so there is no way to relate them to each other.

keep in mind the column names are variable and can change.

thanks in advance.

Comment: the XML:
 
< headerGroup >
 
   <data>
 
       <string> Column 1 </string>
 
  </data>
   <data> 
       <string> Column 2 </string>
 
  </data>
 
</headerGroup >
 
<dataGroup>
 
   <data>
 
          <string> abcd </string>
 
   </data>
     <data> 
          <double> 1234</double>
 
   </data>
 
</dataGroup>
 
<dataGroup>
 
   <data>
 
          <string> xyz</string>
 
   </data>
     <data> 
          <double> 78945</double>
 
   </data>
 
</dataGroup>
 
 expected output:
  Column 1      Column 2
 
-------------     -------------------
 
  abcd             1234
 
  xyz               78945

Comment: Please **do not** put code samples or sample data into comments - since you cannot format it, it's **extremely hard** to read it.... Instead: **update** your question by editing it to provide that additional information! Thank you.

Comment: This is not a valid XML document (it's missing a single **root node**) - it's at best a XML fragment...

Comment: this is just a sample xml that i created to explain my problem. I cannot share the actual xml, sorry.